# Find currency and amount, also ID store in array and paste in Output sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to find the text "Currency" in columns A or B, store all the currencies listed under Currency. Same process for Amount (Can be in an column) 
Store values in an array. Then paste in Output Sheet. The currencies will already be listed in Output sheet in 1st row of the sheet. However if it is a new currency then the code should find last used cell in row 1 and add it. The value of Amount should be added to Output sheet against the currency and ID number also copied from  the Source sheet.

I have some code.

```
    Public Sub loopRow()

    Dim curArray     As Variant
    Dim listarray As Variant
    Dim cnt         As Long

'Find Currency

Dim rgFound As Range
Set rgFound = Range("A:B").Find("Currency")

'Find last used row
    curArray = Cells(rgFound.Address).End(xlUp).Row

    'Transpose list of currecny from the row down from the word Currency that it has found
        listarray = Application.Transpose(Cells(Rows, curArray).End(xlUp)).Row

    For cnt = LBound(curArray) To UBound(curArray)
        curArray(cnt) = curArray(cnt)
    Next cnt
    For cnt = LBound(curArray) To UBound(curArray)
        'Debug.Print curArray(cnt)

    'Copy and paste into Sheet under the correct curreny, if new currency then add this in row A


    Next cnt
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you need to understand your question is unanswerable as is, I'll do my best to help.

The problem we have is not seeing the source sheet the way you do, as we can't see it at all. You say you have the word Currency in columns A or B or both, and an ID column somewhere, and Amount values everywhere. That's tricky source data. If as is more likely, the ID is in a specific column and the amounts are in a set of columns, then we'd have a chance.

Your question outlines the basic steps you'd want to take pretty well, so you're off to a good start.

However you can do all of the work without VBA, certainly if I'm right about the Source data. Create yourself a working sheet, or multiple working sheets. Definitely one to sort out the full list of currencies. Grab a copy of columns A and B (by formulae) and then have the working sheet go through line by line and use logic to build the list. Spreadsheets are great at this.

Once you have the list, use it as row headers on your Output sheet and use sumifs to get the values. I am not sure how the IDs would fit in, but if they were to be your row headings, then do the same as the above to get the list of unique ids and link them into your Output page in column A. Your sumifs can handle that.

That will hardly tell you all you need to know, but if you work it out you'll have learned a lot about Excel and when you need to go into VBA.

If you'd rather do it with VBA, break down each step until it works, and then go onto the next one.

And if you want more help, paste your data in here. Anonymise it first if you need to.